# How to edit an existing wordpress.org site

Tags: installation

I need to edit someone else’s wordpress.org site

They have already gotten hosting and have downloaded wordpress to their host

I am meant to design their site for them (or try to anyways). They made me a log in and password so I can edit their site.

My question is:

1. Do I need to download wordpress.org to edit their site or can I just go to wordpress.org/login and log in and edit the changes there? (I’ve already tried logging in with their u/n and /pw but it doesn’t seem to be working. Not sure if I’m doing something wrong)
2. If I do have to download wordpress myself how do I then go an edit THEIR website? From the tutorials I’ve watched about downloading wordpress.org to a mac, you create your database (or site) right then and there. What happens if someone else has already created their site and has it linked to a domain?

Thanks everyone for your help. I’m such a noob at wordpress!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do a search for "edit wordpress theme". It sounds like it's the "theme" you want to change. You can either modify what they have now, or you can make your own theme from scratch.

If they just want some changes to the theme they have now you'll probably just want to modify a theme, but I'd say learning how to build a theme from scratch would help you understand how it works.

Comment: Yes, I do want to edit their theme...but I first need to figure out how to access their site so I can edit it! How do I do this if they have already downloaded wordpress to their hosting? Do I just log into https://login.wordpress.org/ and type in the u/n and p/w they gave me? (If so, this isn't working which means they gave me the incorrect login). Or is there another way I can edit their site?

Comment: You either need FTP access, or if the permissions allow you to edit theme files you can use an admin login to access their wp-admin and edit the themes in the editor in your browser. The FTP access would use their own host, I believe, so it's probably the domain of their website, but ask them.

Comment: If they gave you the admin login to their blog, just go to http://www.websitename.com/wp-admin and use the login data there.

Comment: Thank you. I tried that and I just get a white blank screen-no log in page. I might have the wrong domain... Just to be clear though, I DO NOT have to download wordpress.org at all to edit their site since they gave me their log in correct? Downloading wordpress is only for if I want to work on my own local server?

Comment: Right! You'd download WP from wordpress.org if you wanted to work locally or upload it onto another domain! If you're not doing that there's no need to download it.